# year in 2year format

Tags: c#

How do I get the following to show in a 2 digit year format?

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Now;
DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString(dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern,dateTimeFormat));
```

Comment: Warning! Answers to this question may not be Y2K compliant. :)

Comment: @djacobsen, but that won't matter until we get a time machine :-) I am much more worried they won't be Y2.1K compliant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard format that does this, you must specify a format:

```
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("M/d/yy",dateTimeFormat));
```

Comment: Specifically, use "yy" instead of "yyyy"

Comment: is the 2 digit year strictly a US way of presenting a date?

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("yy"), dateTimeFormat);
```